# Why does my root login only have basic commands available when ssh'd to ESXi host?

Tags: ssh, vmware-esxi, shell, putty

We are having an issue with our 6.5 ESXi host. As part of our troubleshooting we have enabled ESXi Shell and SSH. Between VMWare Docs and community posts I keep seeing that we are supposed to be able to access the ESXi Shell over SSH.

I am signed in via SSH to the problem host and I am only getting access to basic commands.

```
login as: root
root@10.10.1.5's password:
/admin1-> help
[Usage]
    show   [<options>] [<target>] [<properties>]
           [<propertyname>== <propertyvalue>]
    set    [<options>] [<target>] <propertyname>=<value>
    cd     [<options>] [<target>]
    create [<options>] <target> [<property of new target>=<value>]
           [<property of new target>=<value>]
    delete [<options>] <target>
    exit   [<options>]
    reset  [<options>] [<target>]
    start  [<options>] [<target>]
    stop   [<options>] [<target>]
    version [<options>]
    help   [<options>] [<help topics>]
    load -source <URI> [<options>] [<target>]
    dump -destination <URI> [<options>] [<target>]
/admin1-> ps
cmdstat
        status       : 2
        status_tag   : COMMAND PROCESSING FAILED
        error        : 253
        error_tag    : COMMAND NOT RECOGNIZED
```

I am connected to the ESXi shell on session 0 on the host but a process is hung and I need to stop it (I ran `esxcli` with no parameters and its just letting me keep typing and I can't exit it). However I don't seem to be able to run commands to kill the processes I want.

I am not in there enough to recognize the place I am stuck in. Not the focus of the question but the larger issue we are trying to troubleshoot is the host in unresponsive in vCenter and VMs are up but in a disconnected state

Comment: Hi, The ESX OS is stripped from most command, please check the esx log file for diagnostic help

Comment: Then how I am supposed to access the ESXi Shell over SSH? That is mostly the issue I am trying to solve.

Comment: well, in example for the cli you can use esxcli system <subcommand here>, for available command you can issue a ls in /usr/sbin to see what command you have available

Comment: I am currently connected to the esxishell on session 0 of the host but I cannot type anything in. I thought I could get to another session over ssh, which is what I am trying to do now. On [pubs](https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-51/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.vcli.getstart.doc%2Fcli_jumpstart.3.6.html)  there is nothing special I am told to do for esxishell to work over ssh. My ssh prompt is admin1 as supposed to root user which I find odd.